# websocket on port 443 with /socket.io under kubernetes not working

Tags: python, flask, websocket, kubernetes, minikube

Trying to move my development environment to run on minikube.

The page loads but my page uses websockets on the same port/protocol that the index.html is loaded with (https in this case), and the websockets do no seem to be working correctly.

Here is an example of the correct output when run through nginx / python on my local development box.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Sep/2018 14:14:35] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Sep/2018 14:14:35] "GET /static/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.0" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Sep/2018 14:14:35] "GET /static/socket.io.min.js HTTP/1.0" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Sep/2018 14:14:35] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MNPIg-N HTTP/1.0" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Sep/2018 14:14:35] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.0" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Sep/2018 14:14:35] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.0" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Sep/2018 14:14:35] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MNPIg-o&sid=0570b4fe27f345e9b11858b3acb40a6e HTTP/1.0" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Sep/2018 14:14:35] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MNPIg-r&sid=0570b4fe27f345e9b11858b3acb40a6e HTTP/1.0" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Sep/2018 14:14:35] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MNPIg_x&sid=0570b4fe27f345e9b11858b3acb40a6e HTTP/1.0" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Sep/2018 14:14:35] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MNPIg_w&sid=0570b4fe27f345e9b11858b3acb40a6e HTTP/1.0" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Sep/2018 14:14:40] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MNPIh0L&sid=0570b4fe27f345e9b11858b3acb40a6e HTTP/1.0" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Sep/2018 14:14:45] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MNPIiE3&sid=0570b4fe27f345e9b11858b3acb40a6e HTTP/1.0" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Sep/2018 14:14:50] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MNPIjSI&sid=0570b4fe27f345e9b11858b3acb40a6e HTTP/1.0" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Sep/2018 14:14:55] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MNPIkgS&sid=0570b4fe27f345e9b11858b3acb40a6e HTTP/1.0" 200 -
```

Notice how there is a GET every 5 seconds (that's a timer running on the page)

When running on Kubernetes, The page loads and the timer shows up as if the websocket has worked,  however I show no logs where the websocket is having a GET or POST after the initial one.

```
192.168.99.1,172.17.0.7 - - [14/Sep/2018 18:24:03] "GET /static/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 1210 0.008244
192.168.99.1,172.17.0.7 - - [14/Sep/2018 18:24:03] "GET /static/socket.io.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 1210 0.009271
(10) accepted ('172.17.0.7', 34444)
192.168.99.1,172.17.0.7 - - [14/Sep/2018 18:24:04] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MNPKrsy HTTP/1.1" 200 379 0.003682
(10) accepted ('172.17.0.7', 34446)
192.168.99.1,172.17.0.7 - - [14/Sep/2018 18:24:04] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 1314 0.004694
(10) accepted ('172.17.0.7', 34448)
(10) accepted ('172.17.0.7', 34450)
(10) accepted ('172.17.0.7', 34452)
192.168.99.1,172.17.0.7 - - [14/Sep/2018 18:24:04] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MNPKrtD&sid=77d4755c524f47c2948b9c36da007b85 HTTP/1.1" 200 210 0.000749
192.168.99.1,172.17.0.7 - - [14/Sep/2018 18:24:04] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MNPKrtB&sid=77d4755c524f47c2948b9c36da007b85 HTTP/1.1" 200 194 0.002632
(10) accepted ('172.17.0.7', 34454)
192.168.99.1,172.17.0.7 - - [14/Sep/2018 18:24:04] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 1314 0.002388
```

The Ingress is setup as follows:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: websitev2-cluster-ip-service
              servicePort: 8080
```

As mentioned before, the websocket does not reside on a different port and it is instanciated in javascript as:

```
namespace = '/socket';
var socket = io.connect(location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + namespace);
```

Are there any special requirements to get websockets to work?  I do not believe i need a special route because the URI needs to be sent to the same location as everything else, and on the same port.

EDIT:  MORE DETAILS

My website has a form, that when submitted, executes the following code:

```
    $('form#job').submit(function(event) {
        var nameValue = JSON.stringify($(event.target).serializeArray());
        console.log(nameValue)
        socket.emit('job_submit', {data: nameValue});
        return false;
    });
```

On the python side, I have my socket code, which should get hit once a user clicks the submit button.

```
@socketio.on('job_submit', namespace='/socket')
def job_submit(message):
    print('recieved job_submit message from client')
    # kick off subjob in celery task
    data = unstringify(message)
    print('data = {0}'.format(data))
    sessiondata = dict(session)
    print('sessiondata = {}'.format(sessiondata))
    subjobstart.delay(sessiondata, request.sid, data)
```

In my logs I am not receiving any "recieved job_submit message from client" messages when the submit button is clicked, which means the javascript is trying to send a websocket emit to the python server, but the message is never getting there.

Emits from python to the client page are working as the time is getting updated on the site.

Comment: So websockets show up on kubernetes, but it doesn't work?  What errors do you see?

Comment: I dont see any errors, just after initial page load no socket connections get logged in the debug output of my app.  I will add more info to my question to clear things up more.

Answer (score 1):

So not exactly sure what changed as it worked on test box,  apparently the issue lied in the form validation I was doing.  Once I put in a novalidate option to temporarily bypass the form checking, the form was then able to be submitted and I did not have any websocket issues after all.

Hopefully this post can help someone with the code posted instead.